Sorting the installment numbers of the database according to the 6 digits of the credit / debit card with Ajax
[ajax[controller[incoming data[routeselect option](https://i.sstatic.net/MbargrpB.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/ivMS79j8.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/E6tEvDZP.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/CblkShPr.png)
binlists
Hello Friends
It's been 4 months since I started Laravel and I've started to like it a lot. But I'm stuck on something and I need your help. I made the relevant queries in the attachment and the entire record comes successfully. The problem is that when you type the first 6 digits of the customer card, the number of installments set according to that card number from the relevant database should come in the “select option”.
I need your help and vast knowledge on the subject.
Thank you very much to everyone in advance and wish you success.
<input type="hidden" id="installments_url" value="{{ route('taksit.rastgele') }}">
<div class="field-container">
   <label for="installments_number" class="form-label">Taksit Sayısı</label>
   <select id="installments_number" class="form-select" name="installments_number" data-style="btn-default" required="true">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Taksit Seçiniz</option>
        <option value="1">Tek Çekim</option>
   </select>
</div>   


 <script>
            // Get Installments
            function getInstallments() {
                var installments_url = $('#installments_url').val();
                var data = {
                    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                };
    
                var post = $.post(installments_url, data);
                post.done(function(xhr) {
                    if (xhr.data.length > 0) {
                        var optionsHtml = '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Taksit Seçiniz</option>';
                        xhr.data.forEach(function(item, index) {
                            optionsHtml += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
                            $('#installments_number').html(optionsHtml);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>


    public function rastgeleBinlist()
    {
        $deneme = Binlist::where('installments_number')->orderByRaw('installments_number')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $deneme != null ? $deneme : []
        ]);
    }


please put relevant code in the question

Your question has an [edit] button. As per [ask] you must provide a [mre] of the issue within the question itself - not in pictures, or in links to other sites, or in the Answers area. Please also take the [tour] if you're unfamiliar with how stackoverflow works. Thanks

Could you please share in more details what you are trying to achieve and the results you are currently getting.

to turn the installment rate on and off according to the bin numbers of the cards.

I solved my own question :)
Route
Route::post('/installmentss', [PaymentController::class, 'taksitleriGetir'])->name('installments');

Controller. the card mask was made. that's why I did explode.:)
public function taksitleriGetir(Request $request)
    {
        $credit_card = explode(" ", $request->input('credit_card'));
        $credit_card0 = $credit_card[0]; $credit_card1 = $credit_card[1];
        $cardNumber = $credit_card0.$credit_card1;
        $bin = substr($cardNumber, 0, 6); // Extract first 6 digits

        // Retrieve installment numbers from database based on BIN
        $installments = Binlist::where('bin_code', $bin)->pluck('installments_number')->first();

        $data = json_encode(json_decode($installments, true));
        return response()->json($data);
    }

Ajax
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#getInstallmentsBtn').click(function() {
                var cardNumber = $('#credit_card').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ route('installments') }}",
                    data: {
                        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        'credit_card': cardNumber
                    },

                    success: function(response) {
                        // Clear existing options
                        $('#installmentSelect').empty();
                        var installments = JSON.parse(response);
                        $.each(installments, function(index, value) {
                        $('#installmentSelect').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                            });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Trigger AJAX call when card number input changes
            $('#credit_card').on('input', function() {
                $('#getInstallmentsBtn').click();
            });
        });
</script>

html
<input type="hidden" id="installments_url" value="{{ route('installments') }}">
<button" hidden id="getInstallmentsBtn"></a>
<form id="form_credit_card" method="post" action="{{ route('payment.store') }}" role="form">
      @csrf
<label class="form-label" for="cardnumber">Kart Numarası</label>
<input id="credit_card" class="form-control" name="credit_card" type="text" inputmode="numeric" required>
<div class="field-container">
    <label class="form-label">Taksit Sayısı</label>
        <select id="installmentSelect">
            <option value="">Taksit Seçiniz</option>
        </select>
</div>
</form>

and Conclusion :)
Picture

for="installments_number" doesn't appear to relate to any form elements.

It was forgotten in that copy and paste. :)

You are free to [edit] your posts at any time (so that other people don't copy-paste your code's flaw).
